# Return list of directories containing specified extension

Tags: python

I'd like to get a list of directories below the current directory containing mp3's.

I can get the a list of the files easily enough using `os.walk`. I can get the full path easily enough using `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root), file)`, but I just want a list with of the matching directories. I've tried using `os.path.dirname` and `os.path.pardir`, but all I get with them is `'..'`.

```
import os
l = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
         if file.endswith('.mp3'):
             l.append(os.path.dirname(file))
```

I'm probably missing something obvious?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` already gives you the directory name in each loop; just make that absolute and add to the `l` list. Then move to the next directory (one match is enough):

```
import os
l = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    if any(file.endswith('.mp3') for file in files):
        l.append(os.path.abspath(root))
```

`any()` returns `True` as soon as it finds the first element in the contained iterable that is `True`; so the *first* file that ends with `.mp3` will result in `any()` returning True and the current directory is added to the list of matches.